# dotnet core without typescript (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, .net-core

Is there any possibility to use a .NET Core app without TypeScript?

If I install the vue-.net-core-template with "dotnet new vue" everything is set up with ts-files. But I only want to use pure JavaScript.

Why? For example I will use the module vuejs-localization. It's complicated to get it up and running with ts-files.

So does any template exists which does the same as "dotnet new vue" but only with Javascript?

Comment: have you tried *vue-cli*?

Comment: there is no .net core template with vue-cli. only webpack, browserify and pwa

Comment: okay, just found this one: https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter
looks like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VueJS 2 use -

dotnet new vuejs

This will not create code with TypeScript.

Comment: You forgot to mention that I have to install the template before from nuget: 

dotnet new -i aspnetcore-vuejs

because the templates from github don't provide this option.